# Not seeing console log data in for loop

Tags: angular

I have the below data set that I am trying to loop through. I also have my function thaty does the looping but I cannot see the console logs when i run th application

```
{
    "header": {
        "statuscode": "0",
    },
    "calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment": {
        "responseCode": null,
        "responseDescription": null,
        "calculatorResults": {
            "calculatorResult": [
                {
                    "newCalculatedInstallmentsNo": "63",
                    "newContractEndDate": "20260725",
                    "newResidual": "24031.28",
                    "newInstalment": "5713.38",
                    "newTerm": "72",
                    "outBalanceAvaf": null,
                    "restructureType": "balloon"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
    this.avafService.CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment({accountNumber: '555666'}).subscribe((resp)=>{
      this.confirmData = resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment;
      for(let i = 0; i < this.confirmData; i++) {
        this.calculatorResults = this.confirmData[i].calculatorResults;
        console.log("calculatorResults: "+this.calculatorResults)
        for(let j = 0; j < this.calculatorResults; j++) {
          this.calculatorResult = this.confirmData[i].calculatorResults[j].calculatorResult;
          console.log("calculatorResult: "+this.calculatorResult)
        }
      }
    })
}
```

Any idea why the console logs do not print any data?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I do not see any error in the console

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes I see this. I need another solution to get into the object

Comment: So you need a sum of all the properties in each item in  the `calculatorResult` array is it?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're always going to get `calculatorResult` as an array and we just need to get the sum of the fields present on the Object at the 0th index, here's what you can do:

Try this:

```
calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment() {
  this.avafService
    .CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment({
      accountNumber: '555666'
    })
    .subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.calculatorResults =
        resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment.calculatorResults;
      const [calculatorResult] = this.calculatorResults.calculatorResult;
      this.calculatorResult = Object.keys(calculatorResult).reduce(
        (acc, key) => {
          const value = calculatorResult[key];
          if (!isNaN(+value)) {
            acc += +value;
          }
          return acc;
        },
        0
      );
    });
}
```

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sum-of-properties-in-an-object?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** with the solution code.